# List all programs installed on Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7

I am looking for a program to list (and export) all programs I have installed on my Windows 7 laptop. This will be useful in seeing the useless programs and helpful when I reinstall Windows periodically.

I would like it:

- to be free
- to list **version**, **name** and **install date** of program
- to be lightweight (store on USB and use on any Windows PC)
- simple and quick (less than 5/10 clicks!)
- *not* list Windows Updates (no need for them)
- run on Windows XP+ (definately Windows 7)
- *preferably*, *also* list **product/license** keys for any programs with a key

I don't care which type of file the list is exported as, but preferably as a `.txt` file!

Comment: Just found [this](http://superuser.com/questions/68611/get-list-of-installed-applications-from-windows-command-line). Same question but built-in! You can also use CCleaner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can have a look at [MyUninstaller](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/myuninst.html), from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/).

It's an uninstaller program, however here are its features:

- it's free (as all other utilities from Nirsoft)
- you can choose the information to display in columns: **version**, **name** and **install** date are available
- it is fully portable (as all other utilities from Nirsoft), and lightweight as far as I have experienced it
- you open it (one action), possibly configure the columns to display (2 clicks to open the configuration window), uncheck the display of windows updates (2 clicks), and ask to save the list (1 click on the toolbar icon)
- compatible from Windows 98 to Windows 7
- you have different formats available: txt (3 different kinds, including one with tabulation delimitation), HTML, XML

The only thing I don't know yet is for the product/license keys, but probably Nirsoft has another tool for that.

Feel free to ask for more details/information on how to use it!

Comment: This looks great! Unfortunately it doesn't show product keys :(. I'll try it out ASAP!

Comment: Great software but keep in mind it loads the list of the installed applications from the Registry (i.e. no hd scan).